# facebook integration on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, interaction

the Fackbook or any of the other codes like updating status or etc all these things are working fine in `android 2.1` but in `2.2 (on android device not emulator)` it gives

```
This page contains the following errors:error on line 7 at column 35: xmlParseEntityRef : no name
```

Re-parse document as HTML

Below is the rendering of the page up to the first error.

```
CavalryLogger=false;window._script_path="|?dialog|?uiserver.php";window._EagleEyeSeed="H56D";
```

Request for Permission

I'm in deep trouble because of this, please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer two Link:

1. http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk
2. http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/290-facebook-integration-in-your-android-application

Comment: i hav already done all those things and they work great in android 2.1 or in emulator of 2.2 but on actual device of android 2.2 it gives the above error.....